# How to erase sheet when partial name is written is sheetname?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I tell with VBA that if the name of the worksheet contains the name "name" of part of the word "name"  to completely erase that sheet please??

When the sheet is ok , there is a normal name written in the sheetname

When the sheet is blanc that the sheets are called "name 1" or "name 2" etc till "name 30"

I have to remove the blanc sheets.

Below my attempt, but not working.

```
Sub erasesheet(wbNew As Workbook)   
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

'here I have to be able to tell : I it contains the word "name" in the sheet
'like the code is now it will only look exactly fot sheets with name "name"
      If Sheets.Name = "name"   Then
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         ws.Delete
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     End If
  Next ws
end sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Instr`. Try the following code

```
Sub erasesheet(wbnew As Workbook)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In wbnew.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, UCase(ws.Name), "NAME") Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
      Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, is it possible that we need to add somerhing like *NAME or .NAME or something similar to recognize the partial name, becouse now it seems it is looking for the exact sheetname "NAME"?

Comment: It is not looking for exact name. Instr will search a substring in a string. So if the string contains NAME in it, it will be TRUE. So it is like *NAME. Why do you say its not? Can you provide issue that you are facing.

Comment: how can I SET this code to look for the sheets of the wbnew please?

Comment: @user2151190 - I've updated the answer. Hope it works. Haven't tried though.

Comment: You rock!!!! I adapted little settings and your suggestion did it!!!! Thanks a lot!!!!!!